# Angular - Possible follow up http call needed, what is best approach?

Tags: angular

I have a situation, where I perform a http request to fetch an array of data. However, in some cases the result I'm getting back is an empty array, and if that is the case, I need to perform another get request.

let me illustrate with a code example

```
let name;

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(response => {
    let data = response;
    if (data.length === 0) {
      this.service.getOtherData().subscribe(otherResponse => {
        data = otherResponse;
      });
    }
    this.name = data[0].name;
  });
}
```

I tried to illustrate my current dilemma I'm facing: I need the "name" property of the first entry in the array. However, if the result of the first request is an empty array, I will have to do a follow up call to a different http method.

If the first request returns empty array, the function will still try to assign the "name" property of the first entry in the array, but since that doesn't exist, I get an cannot read "name" of undefined, even before the second http call is performed. If the first response is an empty array, I would like the rest of the function to "wait" with running, until I get response from 2nd http call.

What is the correct approach in this situation? I've looked into mergeMap / switchMap, but it didn't seem  like the right choice, since I won't always have the need for performing multiple requests.

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `switchMap` in this situation.

Try:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
....

name: any; // btw, not let name but just name 

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getData().pipe(
   switchMap(response => {
     // if the length is 0, switch to the new HTTP method
     if (response.length === 0) {
       return this.service.getOtherData();
     } else {
     // if there is a length, keep this response
       return of(response);
     }
   }),
  ).subscribe(data => this.name = data[0].name);
}
```

Comment: This looks like it's exactly what I need :) I will try to test it out, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert them to `Promises` and await them to make it cleaner?

Either way you do it is fine, but if when you have nested requests like you have in your question, sometimes it can start to get confusing.

```js
let name;

async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  const response = await this.service.getData().toPromise();
  if (Array.isArray(response) && response.length > 0) {
    const otherResponse = await this.service.getOtherData().toPromise();
    name = otherResponse[0].name;
  } else {
    name = response[0].name;
  }
}

// Or, better yet. Return the name:

async ngOnInit(): Promise<string> {
  const response = await this.service.getData().toPromise();
  if (Array.isArray(response) && response.length > 0) {
    const otherResponse = await this.service.getOtherData().toPromise();
    return otherResponse[0].name;
  }
  return response[0].name;
}

// Invoking ngOnInit directly is a little awkward,
// but you can. I'm not sure where you're putting
// name, but it needs to be somewhere, obviously.
name = await ngOnInit();
```

You could stay on the `rxjs` path, but I believe you want `exhaustMap` since you have nested calls and you would want to wait for the inner-most observable to complete before returning.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/exhaustmap

Comment: I don't believe the `.toPromise()` will resolve. It needs to be `await this.service.getData().pipe(take(1)).toPromise()`. Same thing with the other one that is getting converted to a promise.

Comment: Yea, that might be true. I'm not sure what that function is doing, but if it's just a GET request via the HttpClient you don't need the `pipe(take(1))` part. Since that's not described, I left that out.

Comment: Oh, I thought for a `GET` request you needed it too. Okay, good to know.